# Are promises flawed?

Tags: scala, future, promise

Like the author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381134/what-are-use-cases-of-scala-promise) I'm trying to understand the reasoning for user-visible promises in Scala 2.10's futures and promises.

Particularly, going again to the [example from the SIP](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html), isn't it completely flawed:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ future, promise }
val p = promise[T]
val f = p.future
val producer = future {
  val r = produceSomething()
  p success r
  continueDoingSomethingUnrelated()
}
val consumer = future {
  startDoingSomething()
  f onSuccess {
    case r => doSomethingWithResult()
  }
}
```

I am imagining the case where the call to `produceSomething` results in a runtime exception. Because promise and producer-future are completely detached, this means the system hangs and the consumer will never complete with either success or failure.

So the only safe way to use promises requires something like

```
val producer = future {
  try {
    val r.produceSomething()
    p success r
  } catch {
     case e: Throwable =>
       p failure e
       throw e  // ouch
  }
  continueDoingSomethingUnrelated()
}
```

Which obviously error-prone and verbose.

The only case I can see for a visible promise type—where `future {}` is insufficient—is the one of the callback hook in M. A. D.'s answer. But the example of the SIP doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thx for link to xiefei's Q.  For some reason this cracked me up: "Depending on the implementation, it may be the case that p.future == p. How can this be ?"  Isn't there some law of temporal consistency that keeps this from happening?

Comment: P.S.: [Another flawed example](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html) -- the whole section "Promises" doesn't make sense. Instead of creating a promise and a helper future, it totally suffices to create one `Future` if I'm not mistaken. Proofs that people are confused by the prominent existence of `Promise` IMO.

Comment: Does the green check mean you accept the argument about composition? Another example is a test runner where some futures are composed to run a test, but reporting is driven by a promise. One reason is that the test monitor can fail the test if it runs too long, etc. Separation of concerns, etc.

Comment: @som-snytt - I don't think any reply clearly answered the question, but I gave check because the timeout example sort of made sense to me. I still feel you can shoot yourself in the foot with promises in the sense that you can miss out cases where the future is never provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Combinators

You can use `Promise` to build additional `Future` combinators that aren't already in the library.

- "Select" off the first future to be satisfied.  Return as a result, with the remainder of the Futures as a sequence: https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/4488970.
- An `after` method that returns a `Future` that is completed after a certain period of time, to "time out" a Future: https://gist.github.com/3804710.

You need Promises to be able to create other combinators like this.

#### Adapt Callbacks

Use `Promise` to adapt callback-based APIs to `Future`-based APIs.  For example:

```
def retrieveThing(key: String): Future[Thing] = {
  val p = Promise[Thing]()

  val callback = new Callback() {
    def receive(message: ThingMessage) {
      message.getPayload match {
        case t: Thing =>
          p success t        
        case err: SystemErrorPayload =>
          p failure new Exception(err.getMessage)
      }
    }
  }

  thingLoader.load(key, callback, timeout)
  p.future
}
```

#### Synchronizers

Build synchronizers using `Promise`.  For example, return a cached value for an expensive operation, or compute it, but don't compute twice for the same key:

```
private val cache = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Promise[T]]

def getEntry(key: String): Future[T] = {
  val newPromise = Promise[T]()
  val foundPromise = cache putIfAbsent (key, newPromise)

  if (foundPromise == null) {
    newPromise completeWith getExpensive(key)
    newPromise.future
  } else {
    foundPromise.future
  }
}
```

Comment: Although your first example doesn't really add anything to `Future.firstCompletedOf`? `def select[A](...) = Future.firstCompletedOf(fs).map { res => Success(res) -> fs.filterNot(_ == fs) }`

Comment: See Viktor's comment at bottom of https://gist.github.com/4504281 for why identity of future is not sufficient book keeping.

Answer (score 7):

This is why you rarely use `success` and `failure` unless you already know something is bulletproof.  If you want bulletproof, this is what `Try` is for:

```
val producer = future {
  p complete Try( produceSomething )
  continueDoingSomethingUnrelated()
}
```

It doesn't seem necessary to throw the error again; you've already dealt with it by packing it into the answer to the promise, no?  (Also, note that if `produceSomething` itself returns a future, you can use `completeWith` instead.)

Comment: Nice Try :) I was just rethrowing the exception for the general case that the producer's future is observed.

Answer (score 1):

Promise has a completeWith(f: Future) method that would solve this problem by automatically handling the success/failure scenarios.

```
promise.completeWith( future {
  r.produceSomething
})
```