# Does Scala future blocks anyway for a long operation?

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka, future, spray, executioncontext

Everywhere we can read that that when performing long running operation or blocking operation it is preferable to use a special Execution context for the matter. Blocking operation like accessing the database. I understand why. It is to avoid Thread starvation. We do not want to have the "8" available threads busy with some blocking code which may eventually return or keep blocking. It either seriously slow down the application or block it indefinitely.

Meanwhile, I'm wondering how things like Spray or Play are implemented. Indeed, let's take the client side. When a request is sent we get a future response. In other words, the request is executed asynchronously. This may by the way end up being a long running operation. However, there is nothing that says launching many request could lead to thread starvation in theses case. Hence i'm wondering why in that case it is not a problem.  Do they have special Thread Pool.

I red in the Book "Learning concurrent programing in Scala" that using the "Blocking {}" statement block in a Future helps its scheduler to spawn more thread automatically. Could it be the way they handle it?

The same thing could be said for receiving request, in play we get to execute an Async Action. If one wants to access a database from this action, shall one use the "Blocking {}" statement block. How to execute that action is a special threadPool/ExecutionContext.

> My assumption here is that they rely on the implicit.global
>   ExecutionContext. Maybe i'm wrong. The Bottom line is. Making request
>   is a long operation by default, how using spray for instance in your
>   code, would handle it such that not to create a Thread Starvation in
>   your code ?

Are we using different ExecutionContext ?

Edit: Just spotted This short presentation [Don't Block - How to Mess Up Akka and Spray](http://www.slideshare.net/zacharycox/dont-block) that happens to better illustrate the problem that I came with here.

In any case i would appreciate to have other opinions

Edit: Here is what i learned that somehow is happening when using a future:

```
def apply[T](body: =>T): Future[T] = impl.Future(body)  //here I have omitted the implicit ExecutorContext
impl.Future is an implementation of Future trait:

def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): scala.concurrent.Future[T] =
{
  val runnable = new PromiseCompletingRunnable(body)
  executor.prepare.execute(runnable)
  runnable.promise.future
}
```

Where PromiseCompletingRunnable looks like this:

```
class PromiseCompletingRunnable[T](body: => T) extends Runnable {
val promise = new Promise.DefaultPromise[T]()

override def run() = {
  promise complete {
    try Success(body) catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }
  }
} }
```

Taken from: [Clarification needed about futures and promises in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960339/clarification-needed-about-futures-and-promises-in-scala)
I red something simpler and similar in the book "Learning concurrent programing in Scala"

> This to me means: there is a Thread in a ThreadPool, that dequeue that task
>   and try to set a promise future value with
>   the result of the execution of that task. If that is correct, i don't see how that task making an IO call does not block the run of that Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take I/O operations as an example, I think the only missing link is I/O multiplexing, which can be implemented by epoll or kqueue.

By using epoll/kqueue, one thread can be waiting on many I/O events **simultaneously**, this thread is waiting (starving) if none of the I/O responses, but you see only this thread is waiting.

Both nginx and nodejs are using this working mode.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're not understanding is that when you make a client request using a blocking API, the thread blocks, sitting there doing nothing, until the response comes back. However if you use an asynchronous API, while you wait for the response to come back, there is no thread waiting. When it comes back, sure, a thread is pulled out of the execution context to do the work, but that's what you want your threads doing - work, not nothing. Having hundreds of threads doing nothing waiting for a client request or database query to return is a waste of resources. And because they aren't free, you have to limit them, and that's where thread starvation comes in. In an asynchronous framework, and thread is only used when there's work to do. This means if you have one thread per CPU core, if you exhaust your thread pool it means your CPUs are 100% utilised, whereas in a blocking framework, you could exhaust your thread pool with only 10% CPU utilisation.  Remember, most average web apps spend most of their time doing IO, that is, waiting for database calls or http client calls to return. The amount of waiting vs the amount of actual work is often an order of magnitude or more greater. So to only use a thread when there's work to be done is a big advantage.

Comment: First of all many thanks for the details answer. However I think, that I understood most of what you said before. Although I think a bit of dissection in your answer would help. U say when you use an asynchronous Ali there is no thread waiting. That Where my question is. I want to how that works? Because to me when you make that call, a future response is created. Hence, there is a runnable somewhere that try to fill a promise with the result of some code. That runnable is there in a thread. To me that is a thread waiting or am I wrong.

Comment: I believe i need to go dig myself into JAVA NIO