# How do I map an Observable with a function from Future to Future?

Tags: scala, rx-scala

Suppose I have an event stream of elements with type `In`:

```
val observableIn: Observable[In] = ???
```

And a function for transforming objects of type `In` into objects of type `Out`, but "in the future":

```
val futureInToFutureOut: (Future[In]) => Future[Out] = ???
```

At this point I want to transform the elements of my `observableIn` according to my function `futureInToFutureOut`. That is, I want as my result an event stream of elements of type `Out`, matching the elements of the original stream, but converted via function `futureInToFutureOut`.

I think this should work:

```
val observableOut: Observable[Out] = observableIn flatMap { in =>
  Observable.from(futureInToFutureOut(Future(in)))
}
```

Is this right? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Your solution is correct as far as I can tell. If you want to improve performance a bit, consider:

```
val observableOut: Observable[Out] = observableIn.flatMap { in =>
  val p = Promise.successful(in)
  Observable.from(futureInToFutureOut(p.future))
}
```

This is a bit faster, as it does not create an asynchronous computation to map the future like [`Future.apply` does](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$).

OLD:

I am leaving my old suggestion below, which works only in the case that you are mapping a single event in the `Observable`.

```
import scala.concurrent._
val promiseIn = Promise[Int]()
observableIn.foreach(x => promiseIn.trySuccess(x))
val observableOut = Observable.create { observer =>
  promiseIn.future.map(futureInToFutureOut).foreach { y =>
    observer.onNext(y)
    observer.onCompleted()
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

Since you are starting out with an `Observable[In]` object (i.e. an event stream), you need to find a way to transfer an event from that `Observable` to a future. The typical way to create a new future is to create its `Promise` first -- the [input side of the future object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960339/clarification-needed-about-futures-and-promises-in-scala). You then use `foreach` on the `Observable` to invoke `trySuccess` on the future when the first event arrives:

```
observableIn ---x---> foreach ---x---> promiseIn.trySuccess(x)
```

Once the event on the `Observable` arrives, the promise will be asynchronously completed. We can now get the reading side of the promise, i.e. the future by calling its `future` method; and then call `map` on the future -- `promiseIn.future.map(futureInToFutureOut)`. Graphically:

```
promiseIn.future ---x---> map ---f(x)---> futureOut
```

The resulting future is asynchronously completed with `futureInToFutureOut(x)`. At this point we need to find a way to emit this value back through an `Observable[Out]`. A typical way to create new `Observable` is to call the `Observable.create` factory method. This method gives as the `Observable`'s writing end -- the `Observer`, which we use to emit events to by calling `onNext`:

```
futureOut ---f(x)---> foreach ---f(x)---> observer.onNext(f(x))
```

Since we know that a future emits at most a single event, we call the `onCompleted` on the observer, to close the output `Observable`.

Edit: if you want to master Rx and Scala futures, you may want to consider [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783281413), which deals with these topics. Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: Can you really achieve this with a single `Promise`? Maybe my question wasn't clear, but my `Observable[In]` contains multiple elements in the stream, and I want to map them all into the `Observable[Out]` stream.

Comment: If there is something wrong with my proposed solution, could you explain what the problem is?

Comment: No, in case you want to map all of the events from the input stream, your solution should be correct, modulo the `flapMap` typo.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your original answer was very informative, if not actually a solution to my problem. I'm actually working on something else for which your example of using `Observable.create` is very helpful. I'm going to read your book as well, it should help me flesh out my understanding of this stuff.

Comment: in your OLD example, I think you need to add a `Subscription()` before the final `}`. on something similar I get a "found: Unit required: Subscription" compiler error.

Comment: Yes, of course - you can add an empty subscription to fix the return type, although, note that calling `unsubscribe` will not actually prevent the future from propagating the event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83253/discussion-between-john-sullivan-and-axel22).