# What is Future and Promise in Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, promise, akka, future

I've just started to learn Akka with the Scala concurrency, but I still don't understand objectives of Promise and Future in concurrency. I've read the official documentation and some another articles I could found but they were pretty bad constructed and didn't shed light for me. Maybe, could someone share any useful link or source? I would be very grateful.

Comment: A future and a promise are connected to each other; see them as 2 ends of a pipe. A promise is the part of the pipe you write to when you have a result ready. A future is the part of the pipe where you wait for the result.

Comment: Sound like the [**Discord** server](https://discord.gg/C7JvttER) would be a better place for this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification needed about futures and promises in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960339/clarification-needed-about-futures-and-promises-in-scala)