# Understanding Scala Futures and Promises

Tags: scala, promise, future

I'm trying to get my head around this concept. I clearly understand what Futures are. I'm little bit bemused with Promises. The code snippet below:

```
val p = Promise[Int]() // gives me a DefaultPromise
val f = p.future // gives me the future computation for the Promise p
```

Now what is the difference between the following two code snippets?

```
p success { 10 }
```

and

```
val x = Future {
  p success { 10 }
}
```

My understanding of the first one is that the p success will complete the future computation associated with that p. Is that computation asynchronous? How is that different to the second code snippet that uses a Future block to complete the Future f associated with Promise p?

Comment: In your example, `p success{10}` and `Future(10)` would be equivalent.
So `Future{ p success { 10 }.future  }` would be like `Future(Future(10))`.
In few words, you are composing a Promise into a Future. 
There is a good description [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

You can think about Promises like a Future you can write in. When you define `p success {x}` you are saying that you are going to build a Future that is going to be successful and will return the value x.

Comment: A promise is the _source_ of a future. The future is what you can subscribe to. A promise specifies how you _create_ the future.

Comment: @Carlos: Thanks for the description. The p success {x} could also result in a failure and is that why we wrap that p success {x} in a Future block?

Comment: I recommend you this tutorial: 
[Promises and futures in practice][1]

There for the code that you are asking for, you cand find the explanation for your code:

A Promise instance is always linked to exactly one instance of Future. If you call the apply method of Future again in the REPL, you will indeed notice that the Future returned is a Promise, too



  [1]: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html

Comment: @user3102968, If you think that there is a computation that can fail, you can just wrap it in a in a Future in case the promise is not needed.
In other case, If you have a failure you can use `p failure trowable`.

Comment: They are different in the sense that first one completes the `Future` associated with `p` on the spot or immediately but the second one will complete it *later*.

Comment: I'm still not making sense of it. Why would I need Promises when I can use a Future? Is it because you cannot pass a value into a Future block, you do that with a Promise?

Comment: @user3102968, I think that is the point. I think you will use `Future` most of the time. [In this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381134/what-are-the-use-cases-of-scala-concurrent-promise) you can find the use cases for promises. I will write all of this in a response to sum it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you can consider equivalent `p success { 10 }` and `Future(10)`. You will only need to extract the future from p to get the same result.

You may consider Promises as a writeable `Future` where you will define the success or failure of the computation. As it looks a bit imperative programming, you will probably use them in very particular cases. You can see some of those cases in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381134/what-are-the-use-cases-of-scala-concurrent-promise).

Comment: Isn't p.success { 10 }.future equal to Future(10)? p success { 10 } is a Promise.type!

Comment: You are right. You need to extract the Future of the promise using the function `.future` to get the same result.