# Usage of completeWith in scala promises

Tags: scala, concurrency, promise

Here is an example from the official doc:

```
val f = Future { 1 }
val p = Promise[Int]
p completeWith f
p.future onSuccess {
  case x => println(x)
}
```

It seems too much ceremony, since the idea can be expressed more concisely:

```
f onSuccess {
  case x: Int => println(x)
}
```

How is `completeWith` useful in the real world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promises` are usually used to create more complex combinators and methods for `Future`, you can see it is extensively used in implementation of `Future`

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L1

It is rarely used in regular code unless you want to extend functionality of `Future` or create your own async api.

There is an interesting course on Coursera https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive that covers `Futures`. In the assignment you are supposed to implement and use many different methods for `Future`, and `Promises` are very helpful or even required to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A `Promise` is a write once value that is completed by whoever writes to it first. In some cases it's useful when there are multiple `Future`s competing to complete it. In your example it's obviously not that useful, but that's not always the case.

Edit: found a longer explanation here: [What are the use cases of scala.concurrent.Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381134/what-are-the-use-cases-of-scala-concurrent-promise).