# Uses of Promise over Try

Tags: scala, promise

I've been reading a bit on asynchronous programming in Scala and I am struggling to understand the uses of [Promise](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Promise.html) trait.

> A Promise is an object which can be completed with a value or failed with an exception.

Looking at the documentation, you can pass a [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) or an actual value to the Promise and perform operations from there.

What I am confused about is why do we need the Promise trait at all? What functionality does it offer that the Try class does not offer directly by itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the use cases of scala.concurrent.Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381134/what-are-the-use-cases-of-scala-concurrent-promise)

Comment: Promise is asynchronous, creating another thread for executing code. Try is synchronous executing code in the same thread

Comment: Actually, Promise doesn't create thread, but it is used internally by Future which require a thread to exist. And Future is asynchronous Try.